# Convert exponential number to full number

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

Convert `"2.3456754342345466E+36"` to full number:

```
var sm = Convert.ToDouble(splitted[0]) + Convert.ToDouble(splitted[1]);  

**//sm value is === "2.3456754342345466E+36"**

var d = Decimal.Parse(sm.ToString(), 
System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
if (splitted[0].Length ==Convert.ToString(d).Length)
 {
 sum.Add(""+sm);
 }
else
{
 sum.Add(""+splitted[0]);
}
```

`Decimal.Parse(sm.ToString()` is throwing:

> Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal.

Can someone help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `decimal` maximum value is about `7.9e+28`, so it cannot fit your number. You need to store it in a `double`. When you want to print put the number, you can format it in any way you want using the `ToString()` method with formatting specifier. For example, `F0` will give a straight number with no fraction:

```
var sm = "2.3456754342345466E+36";
var d = double.Parse(sm, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("F0")); //Prints 2345675434234550000000000000000000000
```

Comment: It works fine but at the end i am getting full of zeros but i need exact result because i am doing sum operation

Comment: What do you mean? This **IS** an exact result. Those zeros are part of your number which has `+36` digits. If you don't want the zeros at the end and you only want `234567543423455`, then this is a completely different number which is `2.34567543423455e+14`. If you use this number `2.34567543423455e+14` with the code in my answer, you will have no zeros. If you want to start with `+36` and remove the zeros, then you can simply trim them like this `d.ToString("F0").TrimEnd('0')`.

Comment: d.ToString("F0").TrimEnd('0') helped for me to solve my problem. Thank you.